# Display data based on conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I allow a file to be uploaded.  At the time of the upload a month is selected.  Now within my view, I pass all the data relating to an upload, unique to the month.  Essentially, my view ends up with something like this

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#235 ▼
    +"id": 11
    +"upload_month": "Janaury"
    +"MAX(created_at)": "2017-01-30 13:25:59"
  }
  1 => {#236 ▼
    +"id": 10
    +"upload_month": "April"
    +"MAX(created_at)": "2017-01-30 13:22:39"
  }
]
```

Now I am looking to display the data for whatever months I have within tabs.  I have removed most of the months for demonstration purposes

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#January" data-toggle="tab">JAN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#February" data-toggle="tab">FEB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#March" data-toggle="tab">MAR</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="January">
        <h3>Jan Data</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="February">
        <h3>Feb Data</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="March">
        <h3>Mar data</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the data that is passed the the view (which contains the month that data relates too), how can I display it within the appropiate tab?

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to leverage the built in [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-groupby) method in your controller:

```php
// instead of
// return $someDataObject;
return $someDataObject->groupBy('upload_month');
```

Then in the view you can foreach on the month keys:

```php
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#January" data-toggle="tab">JAN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#February" data-toggle="tab">FEB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#March" data-toggle="tab">MAR</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="January">
        <h3>Jan Data</h3>
        @foreach($collectionOfData['January'] as $monthData)
            {{ $monthData->id }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="February">
        <h3>Feb Data</h3>
        @foreach($collectionOfData['February'] as $monthData)
            {{ $monthData->id }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="March">
        <h3>Mar data</h3>
        @foreach($collectionOfData['March'] as $monthData)
            {{ $monthData->id }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
    .....
</div>
```

Exact implementation depends on your code of course, but this should get you started.

You could even simplify the code more if you did some sorting on the back end (so that the months were in the correct order), something like:

```
return $someDataObject->groupBy('upload_month')->sortBy('someDateRepresentationOfTheMonthTheDataRepresents');
```

And in the view:

```php
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @foreach($collectionOfData as $monthName => $monthData)
        {{-- This uses the $loop variable which is only available in Laravel 5.3 and above --}}
        <li class="<?php if($loop->first) { echo 'active'; } ?>"><a href="#{{ $monthName }}" data-toggle="tab"><?php strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($monthName))); ?></a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    @foreach($collectionOfData as $monthName => $monthData)
        {{-- This uses the $loop variable which is only available in Laravel 5.3 and above --}}
        <div class="tab-pane <?php if($loop->first) { echo 'active'; } ?>" id="{{ $monthName }}">
            <h3><?php date('M', strtotime($monthName)); ?> Data</h3>
            @foreach($monthData as $monthDataPieces)
                {{ $monthDataPieces->id }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```